# How to Replace Values Between View Controllers?

Tags: ios, json, uipickerview, segue, nsurl

I'm building an iOS app that parses JSON data when the first ViewController loads. In another ViewController, I have a UIPicker, which includes an array objects that pass their own corresponding urls, and a UIButton which calls the segue back to the first ViewController. However, when I call the segue, the View Controller still parses the same data from the initial nsurl, instead of the data called to replace it. How do I fix this so that when I select an object from the UIPicker and pass the data to the next controller, the first view controller parses that data accordingly?

Here is my code:

**MainVC.m**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

[super viewDidLoad];

_bburl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/api/sites?count=75"];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:_bburl];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:_bburl];
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [session downloadTaskWithURL:_bburl completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
        NSLog(@"%@", response);

        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:location];

        NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];



. . . . .

}
```

**MenuVC.m**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

[super viewDidLoad];

 self->catArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"All",@"4-Letter", @"Animal", @"Auction", @"Blog", @"Business", @"Celluar", @"Children",@"Community", @"Consulting", @"Dating", @"Design", @"Download", nil];


 self->URLArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [URLArray addObject: @"https://www.example.com/api/sites/?count=75"];

    [URLArray addObject: @"https://www.example.com/api/sites/?count=75&category=4-letter"];
    [URLArray addObject: @"https://www.example.com/api/sites/?count=75&category=animal"];
    [URLArray addObject: @"https://www.example.com/api/sites/?count=75&category=auction"];
    [URLArray addObject: @"https://www.example.com/api/sites/?count=75&category=blog"];
    [URLArray addObject: @"https://www.example.com/api/sites/?count=75&category=business"];
    [URLArray addObject: @"https://www.example.com/api/sites/?count=75&category=cellular"];
    [URLArray addObject: @"https://www.example.com/api/sites/?count=75&category=children"];
    [URLArray addObject: @"https://www.example.com/api/sites/?count=75&category=community"];
    [URLArray addObject: @"https://www.example.com/api/sites/?count=75&category=consulting"];
    [URLArray addObject: @"https://www.example.com/api/sites/?count=75&category=dating"];
    [URLArray addObject: @"https://www.exapmle.com/api/sites/?count=75&category=design"];
    [URLArray addObject: @"https://www.example.com/api/sites/?count=75&category=download"];



 self->picker = catArray;

}



-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {

    // This method returns the number of components we want in our Picker.
    // The components are the colums.

    return 1;

}


-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    // This returns the number of rows in each component. We use the count of our array to determine the number of rows.

   return [self->catArray count];

    return 0;

}

#pragma mark Picker Delegate Methods

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    return [self->catArray objectAtIndex:row];

    return 0;

}


-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
   {
       selectedRow = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];

       NSString *catURLString = [URLArray objectAtIndex:selectedRow];
       catURL = [NSURL URLWithString:catURLString];
       MainViewController *mainVC = [[MainViewController alloc]init];
       mainVC.bburl = catURL;

       NSLog(@"%d, %@", selectedRow, catURL);
   }


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"backFromMenuSegue"])   {
    NSString *catURLString = [URLArray objectAtIndex:[self->picker selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    catURL = [NSURL URLWithString:catURLString];

    MainViewController *mainVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        mainVC.bburl = catURL;

        NSLog(@"Selected url: %@",catURL);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call the segue back to the first ViewController the first viewController has already loaded. So method `viewDidLoad` will not be called. The quickest and dirty way to solve this is move all the code in `viewDidLoad` to `viewWillAppear`

Comment: @iOSLove14 Have you update UI (reload data) after asynchronous network request?

Comment: How/where do I put that line of code to reload it in the Main View Controller? I don't want reload the data in the picker.. @dopcn